# How to not show parent folders in Encode explorer?

Tags: php

I'm using the PHP extension for browsing files on my server.

Now i'd like to lock the view to only one folder.
Subfolders are ok, but clicking the dots to view parent folder is not ok.

How can i solve this?

I have tried to disable this row:

```
//
// Display breadcrumbs (relative path of the location).
// Default: $_CONFIG['show_path'] = true;
//
$_CONFIG['show_path'] = false;
```

Encode explorer demo:
http://encode-explorer.siineiolekala.net/explorer/index.php

Github script:
https://github.com/marekrei/encode-explorer/blob/master/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove lines 3114 to 3119 and ".." will be removed from all dirs...

```
<tr class="row two">
    <td class="icon"><img alt="dir" src="?img=directory" /></td>
    <td colspan="<?php print (($this->mobile == true?1:(GateKeeper::isDeleteAllowed()?4:3))); ?>" class="long">
        <a class="item" href="<?php print $this->makeLink(false, false, null, null, null, $this->location->getDir(false, true, false, 1)); ?>">..</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But if you have some subfolders to go in and out, better is to put under some IF statement... (i prefer this solution)

for example don't display ".." only if you are in root dir, in other dirs display:

```
<?php if ( !empty($_REQUEST['dir']) ): ?>
    <tr class="row two">
        <td class="icon"><img alt="dir" src="?img=directory" /></td>
        <td colspan="<?php print (($this->mobile == true?1:(GateKeeper::isDeleteAllowed()?4:3))); ?>" class="long">
            <a class="item" href="<?php print $this->makeLink(false, false, null, null, null, $this->location->getDir(false, true, false, 1)); ?>">..</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.